# How to use a jquery plugin in a component with Svelte

Tags: jquery, components, svelte

I would like to use footable.js jquery plugin in a Svelte component. And I'm a newbie with Svelte:
I put the link to the js and the css files in the head special element of the app.svelte:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/footable.metro.css" >
  <script src="assets/jquery.js" ></script> 
    <script src="assets/footable-albu.js" ></script> 
</head>
```

I created the Footable.svelte component:

```
<script>
import { onMount, tick } from 'svelte';
    
    let el ;// table element
    
    
    onMount(() => {
        table = jQuery(el).footable();  
    
    })  
</script>
```

When I run the app I get "Footable.svelte:8 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined", but when I type in the dev tools console jQuery I can see it's defined...
I think there is some sort of timing or life cycle problem between the call to the component and the lodaing of Jquery, but dont understand How to correct this.
(Besides this I don't know where is the right place to put the footable plugin files: wether in the public folder or in the source. Should I config rollup for this.)

Comment: head in svelte file is handled widh `<svelte:head>` not with `<head>`
Also, try to insert your script tags in the public/index.html instead (with standard `<head>` this time)

Comment: Thanks, I will look . But concerning the script tag in the index.html, I'm looking more for a solution where my componant could be self containning the reference it needs to be used possibly in another app.